# Reading Buffers in Java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, colors, buffer

I need a bit of a hand reading the buffer that is spat out by the glReadPixels feature in android's opengl-es api. Here is my code so far...

```
public static void pick(GL11 gl){
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        IntBuffer pixel = IntBuffer.allocate(384000);

        mColourR = BaseObject.getColourR();
        mColourG = BaseObject.getColourG();
        mColourB = BaseObject.getColourB();

        x = MGLSurfaceView.X();
        y = MGLSurfaceView.Y();

        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT,viewport,0);

        gl.glReadPixels((int)x,viewport[3]-(int)y, 1, 1, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);


}
```

the name of the output buffer in this code is "pixel" what do I need to add to this code to get the colour values back from the "pixel" buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [get() methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get%28int%29) of the `IntBuffer` to access individual values.

RGB color values are usually stored in that very order, so calling `pixel.get(0)` will get you the red value of the first pixel, `pixel.get(1)` will get you the green channel and so on. Usually, the values are stored line-wise.

So, if you need a value for a particular pixel, (x,y) you will have to call `get(screenWidth*3*y + x)`

By the way, you can retrieve the raw int array from your `IntBuffer`by calling `pixels.array()`

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to have done it my log tags show that the values always come back black (0, 0, 0)

Comment: I think that in that case the problem is not with the retrieving the values. This one is pretty straighforward. Maybe you could align the pixel types by making your Buffer a ByteBuffer in order to correspond to GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE of the readPixels call? This one is a wild guess though.

Comment: No that didn't do it, my viewport is showing my the right values I tried putting in set values for x and y and i've set my clear colour to blue to see if it was just inaccurate and was in fact missing my object coordinates and picking the background colour but nothing. hmm well I guess you have already answered my question so

Comment: glad you could clarify the issue. Cheers